# Value not showing when component loads

Tags: angular

I have a value that I want to display as soon as the component loads. It is a mathematical calculation that gets done to work out the value. The calculation is simply a drop-down value multiplied by a another value stored in a cache.

Here is my code

```
  ctc = 50000;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.percentage = this.memberContributionPercentages[0].value;
    this.getRetirementPercentage(event);
  }

  getRetirementPercentage(event) {
    this.percentage = event.value;
    this.totalContribution = this.ctc * (this.percentage / 100);
  }  

  <div class="total-contributions">
    <strong>Total contributions</strong>
    <p class="total-calculation">R{{totalContribution}}</p>
  </div>
```

Currently my problem is that the value shows NAN, any ideas? Total contribution is the value I am trying to display.

Comment: What is the value of `this.percentage` and `event`?

Comment: It's because, in your ngOnInit, you are calling `getRetirementPercentage(event)` but event is undefined in that instance.

Comment: because in ngOnInit 
this.getRetirementPercentage(event); 
'event' doesn't have any value that's why calculation shows NAN.

Comment: I think this `this.percentage` is a string

Comment: please be more specific while writing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to define proper types to each and every variable you have used.
I guess the issue is occurred because you are trying to multiply number with some string or any other data type.

One of the other ways without using typings is that you can use parseFloat :-

```
    this.totalContribution = parseFloat(this.ctc) * (parseFloat(this.percentage) / 100);
```

Maybe this can solve your issue, but it isn't the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.percentage = this.memberContributionPercentages[0].value;
    this.getRetirementPercentage(event);
  }
```

because you not providing any value to this value event is not declare any value or  event is undefined in that instance

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.percentage = this.memberContributionPercentages[0].value;
    this.getRetirementPercentage(this.percentage);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**`NAN`** basically stands for **`Not A Number`**

Try this in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.percentage = this.memberContributionPercentages[0].value;
    this.getRetirementPercentage(this.percentage);
  }
```

Comment: you just repeat my answer

Comment: I dont thinks so. Did you answer OP's this question `Currently my problem is that the value shows NAN, any ideas?` properly?